# How do i configure samba on my Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

Am trying to set up Samba and cant seem to get the correct configuration for `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.

Comment: What is your current config?  What are you trying to accomplish.  What issues are you having?  Please help us help you buy providing additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows machine must be on same workgroup. To check the value in windows machine run the command at cmd prompt

```
net config workstation
```

Your windows machine must be at same Workstation domain as in ubuntu server.
To make the windows machine reachable in windows proceed like this. In the run terminal & add  the entry of your server IP address

```
notepad C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

To configure samba edit the file `/etc/samba/smb.cnf` before making changes I will make the backup of original file as  `/etc/samba/smb.cnf.bak`

```
mv /etc/samba/smb.cnf /etc/samba/smb.cnf.bak
```

Further give the entries like this

```
vi /etc/samba/smb.cnf
```

For further details I need more information about the problem.